# Create a list within list for specific changes in index

Tags: python

What I have is a list (large one) from an imported CSV file that had a bunch of data. It is weather data spanning over an entire year. So 12 months of data. the months are represented as 1 - 12:
please look at the image:

[image]

Please note I **CAN NOT** import any modules!

As you can see, the number after the year in each index is the month (eg. 01, 02, 03 etc) What I want to do is create a list for each month within this list e.g. [['2011,01,...,...],[2011,02,...,...]].

How do I go about doing that?

My current code for opening and adding the CSV data to a list:

```
try:
    fp = open(filename, "r")
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        cols = line.split(',')
        cols = cols[1:]
        data.append(','.join(cols))



    fp.close()

    print(data[1:])


except IOError:
     print("Error!!! Opening file...")
```

Comment: What's the problem with `line.split(',')`?

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to output. For each line you can split it by `','`, which creates a list you can append to another list. And you didn't mention what's wrong with the current output. Can you specify expected outcome?

Comment: Sorry, I am still very new to Python. Right now if you print what I have above with the right CSV file you have the output I got in the image provided. What I want it to separate each month into it's own list within the current list. So like [[month 1],[month2],[month3], etc]

Comment: So you only need the month be in the result list right? Why would you wrap it in an inner list then?

Comment: No, not just the month, I am saying that it needs to be separated by month. I you look at my image If linked you can see there is a lot more than just the month in each index. So all of the January(01) needs to be in a list all of the February(02) in another etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to import, create a dict for each month that has an empty array as a value in that dict. Then load the data into the dict, appending the data to the array for that month.

```
month_dict = {}
for k in range(12):
    month_dict[k+1] = []

try:
    fp = open('example.csv', "r")
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
        line = line.strip()
        cols = line.split(',')
        cols = cols[1:]
        month_dict[int(cols[1])].append(cols)
    fp.close()
    print(month_dict)
except IOError:
     print("Error!!! Opening file...")
```

To get the data list for that month read the `dict[month]`. Remember to convert to `int`s.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I have been stuck on this for hours and you helped me break through thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for the pandas package `pip3 install pandas`.

With pandas you can read csv files with the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function. Once you have that dataframe you can select all months.

Here is some example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2012', '01', '29'],
                   ['2012', '01', '30'],
                   ['2012', '01', '31'],
                   ['2012', '02', '01'],
                   ['2012', '02', '02'],
                   ['2012', '02', '03'],],
                 columns=['year', 'month', 'day'])
df[df['month']=='01']
```

Which outputs:

```
    year    month   day
0   2012    01      29
1   2012    01      30
2   2012    01      31
```

To read the csv you can use this code in the place of my example dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
```

I would recommend you use pandas for what you want to do from there on. But if you absolutely need your data as a list of lists you can do:

```
list(df[df['month']=='01'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1))
```

Which outputs:

```
[['2012', '01', '29'], ['2012', '01', '30'], ['2012', '01', '31']]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without pandas or csv? I'm doing an assignment and we are not allowed to import anything.

Comment: No, I'm simply stuck at this stage. I have been at this for hours and I have been unable to figure out how to sort all of this information into lists based on the months it is from. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Posted a new answer without imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the csv module in python and read it as a dictionary like this

```
import csv
def read_csv_to_dict(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        a = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')]
    return a

data = read_csv_to_dict(filename)
```

Then data is a list of dictionaries with one line per row.

I think that is a good start, paste the file if you need more help.